# Is wifi.suspend() not available in builds from NodeMCU Custom Builder?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I am running into this error when making a call to `wifi.suspend(0)`

```
The option "PMSLEEP_ENABLE" in "app/include/user_config.h" was disabled during FW build!
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (/opt/lua/myfile.lua:12: wifi.suspend is unavailable)
```

Docs say `wifi.suspend()` is off by default.

Does this mean I have to build my own firmware if I need `wifi.suspend()` enabled?

Is the option to flip the flag available via the [Online Build Tool](https://nodemcu-build.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I have to build my own firmware if I need
>   wifi.suspend() enabled?

Yes.

> Is the option to flip the flag available via the Online Build Tool?

No.